# php not responding to form submission

Tags: php, forms

The page simply gets reloaded when I submit the form.Even when I change the PHP file for action the result is the same.No output telling me the status of how my code ran. The PHP i have shared is login.php

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $n=$_POST['name'];
        $p=$_POST['pass'];
        $q="SELECT NAME FROM user
            WHERE name='$n' and password='$p';";
        $res=$conn->query($q);
        echo "k";
        echo "<script>window.alert('here')</script>";
        if($res->num_rows == 1)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name']=$n;
            $_SESSION['pass']=$p;
            echo "<a href='cust.php'>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML='<i>please enter valid name and password</i><br></script>'";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />-->
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="login.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <!--<b>First Day of stay</b><input type="date" name="start"><br><br>
        <b>Last Day of stay</b><input type="date" name="start"><br><br>-->
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name"><br><br>
        <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" text="login">
        <span id="resp">
        </span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any form fields named submit

Comment: @JohnConde amongst others ;-)

Comment: then storing passwords in plain text and doing this... `$_SESSION['pass']=$p;` scary.

Comment: nice stealth edit and without marking it as an edit. and using an answer below.

Comment: ^ @JohnConde OP pulled a fast one. I'm not reopening.

Comment: I performed a rollback to your original post. Please do NOT change your question like that.

Comment: I have edited please try the code again it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply it to your query.

Comment: sry i'm new to this site so i was unaware about that :(

Comment: what is acceptable is to post a comment under an answer given stating that what they posted did not solve the problem. You can also edit your question BUT not overwriting your original post and adding to your question under the original post, the code that you did modify and writing that it is an EDIT in bold. Again, check for errors for your query. The link I gave you above shows you how to check for that.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Is it because of the $_SESSION=$p thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little correction:

```
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name"><br><br>
 <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="password"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" text="login">
```

Comment: OP pulled a "fast one" on you/everyone.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand what you are saying :(

Comment: it doesn't work with those changes either :(

Comment: the person who posted their question made an edit with everything you posted and not marking it as an edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33331097/2. I performed a rollback to their original post.